# Adding a "When, Then" clause

Tags: c#, linq, case

I have a LINQ query to populate my admin dashboard table. Within it, i have a `case` statement to populate fields, based on the campaign's date. (I.e., if start date is less then `DateTime.Now`, then it will be displayed as active, as you will see below.) What i want to do is add a `where` condition within that case statement, to update `EndDate` to `DateTime.Now`, making it closed. The condition to check is whether my `Uptake` has reached my `Target`, meaning if the required target for the campaign has been met, then the campaign is closed. Can someone please help me?

```
MSCDatabaseDataContext MSCDB = new MSCDatabaseDataContext();
var q =
    from row in MSCDB.Tbl_Campaigns
    where row.CampaignStatus != 4
    select new Campaign
    {
        CampaignID = row.CampaignId,
        CampaignName = row.CampaignName,
        Target = Convert.ToInt32(row.Target),
        Discount = Convert.ToInt32(row.Discount),
        CampaignStartDatesS =
            Convert.ToDateTime(row.StartDate).Date + " - " +
            Convert.ToDateTime(row.EndDate).Date,
        //CampaignSDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row.StartDate),
        //CampaignEDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row.EndDate),
        CurrentStatus =
            (row.EndDate >= DateTime.Now && row.StartDate <= DateTime.Now) ? "Active" :
            row.StartDate >= DateTime.Now ? "Pending" :
            row.CampaignStatus == 4 ? "Archived" : "Closed",
        Uptake = Convert.ToInt32(row.Uptake),
    };
```

Comment: using fluent syntax, `collection.Where(a => a.CampaignStatus != 4).Select()`.

Comment: You can do multiple condition using `where <condition1> && <condition2>`

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, Hey man. Uhm im still very new to development. Could you please be a bit more specific. Also, it says Collection does not exist in the current context. Is it because im not putting it in the right place?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do like this:

```
MSCDatabaseDataContext MSCDB = new MSCDatabaseDataContext();
var q = from row in MSCDB.Tbl_Campaigns
where row.CampaignStatus != 4
select new Campaign
{   
    CampaignID = row.CampaignId,
    CampaignName = row.CampaignName,
    Target = Convert.ToInt32(row.Target),
    Discount = Convert.ToInt32(row.Discount),
    CampaignStartDatesS = Convert.ToDateTime(row.StartDate).Date + " - " + Convert.ToDateTime(row.EndDate).Date,
    //CampaignSDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row.StartDate),
    CampaignEDate = Convert.ToInt32(row.Uptake) == Convert.ToInt32(row.Target) ? DateTime.Now : null,
    CurrentStatus = row.EndDate >= DateTime.Now && row.StartDate <= DateTime.Now ? "Active": row.StartDate >=  DateTime.Now ? "Pending": row.CampaignStatus == 4 ? "Archived": "Closed",
    Uptake = Convert.ToInt32(row.Uptake),

};
```

Comment: It says "Type of conditional expression can not be determined because there is no implicit conversion between system.DateTime and <null>". What does the null stand for in this context? @User449689

Comment: @KeiFrancois is CampaignEDate a DateTime or a DiteTime? (nullable)? Look at my edited answer anyway

Comment: Not sure why but it game me this error "SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.". @User449689

Comment: @KeiFrancois ok, you are right, in SQL it's not possible to use a DateTime.MinValue because is not in the range of date managed by SQL Server. Therefore, edit your CampaignEDate property and declare it as DateTime? this mean that it will accept null values. And change the query as my first version (I have edited the answer again)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `let` to pre-compute values for use in the `select`:

```
var q = from row in MSCDB.Tbl_Campaigns
        let target = Convert.ToInt32(row.Target)
        let uptake = Convert.ToInt32(row.Uptake)
        where row.CampaignStatus != 4
        select new Campaign
        {
            CampaignID = row.CampaignId,
            CampaignName = row.CampaignName,
            Target = target,
            Discount = Convert.ToInt32(row.Discount),
            CampaignStartDatesS = Convert.ToDateTime(row.StartDate).Date + " - " + Convert.ToDateTime(row.EndDate).Date,
            CurrentStatus = uptake >= target ? "Closed" : row.EndDate >= DateTime.Now && row.StartDate <= DateTime.Now ? "Active": row.StartDate >=  DateTime.Now ? "Pending": row.CampaignStatus == 4 ? "Archived": "Closed",
            Uptake = uptake
        };
```

Comment: Hey man, your sollution looks viable. The thing is, i dont just want it disyplayed as closed. I want to physically update the database EndDate Column to GetDate(). So basically i want row.EndDate To = DateTime.Now, IF Uptake = Target. @DavidArno

Comment: @KeiFrancois You can't do that via LINQ. LINQ is for processing data; not for writing changes back to the database.

Comment: Can i call a stored procedure to manually update within the DB? @DavidArno